# Why I can delete my user from an old phone without deleting everything on my new one?

Tags: user-interface

So, I bought a new phone (Nexus 5) and I created my account and user. My old phone (Nexus 4) has the same user as a matter of fact, the problem is that I gave my old phone to my mother so she could have a better phone. But, several things are sync between the phones, like the photos and the calendar. I tried to create a new user for her or even delete my user from the old phone but I couldn't find any option to do that. Any suggestion on how to solve that? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new Google account for your mother, and then delete your own Google account from the phone.

To add an account:

> - On your mobile device, open the Settings menu .
> - Under "Accounts," touch Add account.

This is how to delete your account.

> If you're using a device with multiple users, each user has separate account settings so make sure you’re logged in as the correct user before removing any account information.
>
> - Open the Settings menu  on your device.
> - Under "Accounts," touch the name of the account you want to remove.
> - If you’re using a Google account, touch Google and then the account. Important: When you remove your Google Account, all the email, contacts, Calendar events, and other data associated with that account will no longer automatically sync with your device.
> - Touch the Menu icon Menu in the top right corner of the screen.
>     Touch Remove account. If this is the only Google account on the device, you may need to enter your device's pattern, PIN, or password as a security measure. This ensures that only you or someone you trust is removing the account from your device.

Source: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2840815?hl=en